# Getting a distinct value across 2 union sql server tables

Tags: sql, union, distinct, distinct-values

I'm trying to get all distinct values across 2 tables using a union.

The idea is to get a count of all unique values in the columnA column without repeats so that I can get a summation of all columns that contain a unique columnA.

This is what I tried (sql server express 2008)

```
select 
    count(Distinct ColumnA) 
from 
( 
    select Distinct ColumnA as ColumnA from tableX where x = y
    union
    select Distinct ColumnA as ColumnA from tableY where y=z
)
```

Comment: And what isn't working exactly? You have some superfluous DISTINCTs but otherwise this should work.

Comment: What are you getting so far that leads you believe what you have is incorrect?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct tmp.ColumnA) FROM ( (SELECT ColumnA FROM TableX WHERE x=y) 
UNION (SELECT ColumnA FROM TableY WHERE y=z) ) as tmp
```

The extra distincts on TableX and TableY aren't necessary; they'll get stripped in the tmp.ColumnA clause.  Declaring a temporary table should eliminate the ambiguity that might've prevented your query from executing.

Comment: The DISTINCT in the COUNT(DISTINCT isn't necessary because `UNION` removes duplicates

Comment: THis worked for me.  I simply had to add as ColumnA at the end of the union'd select statement

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA From TableX WHERE x = y
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA From TableY WHERE y = z
) t
```

Using a "UNION" will not return duplicates. If you used "UNION ALL" then duplicate ColumnA values from each table WOULD be return.

Comment: DISTINCT isn't necessary because of the UNION, which removes duplicates.  `UNION ALL` does **not** remove duplicates

Comment: True - I just thought including the distinct in there might be more performant (execution plan is different) - would require a bit more testing to prove/disprove that. Re: UNION ALL, that is what I said :)

Answer (score 4):

To get distinct values in Union query you can try this

```
Select distinct AUnion.Name,AUnion.Company from (SELECT Name,Company from table1 UNION SELECT Name,Company from table2)AUnion
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name
FROM   TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name
FROM   TableB
WHERE  TableB.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM TableA)
```