# TSQL: How to skip double record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can use following query in ms access.

```
SELECT DISTINCT JobCardNo, custnm
FROM            JobCardDetails
ORDER BY JobCardNo DESC
```

the output is

```
JobcardNo CustNm
189        sagar
188        sagar
187        shiva
```

but i want output like

```
JobcardNo CustNm
189        sagar
187        shiva
```

Comment: don't include tags in title, rather use a proper question tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a distinct value across 2 union sql server tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891016/getting-a-distinct-value-across-2-union-sql-server-tables)

Comment: but i want to get all record in 1 table

Comment: Please use the [formatting features](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future. I did some formatting for now.

Answer (score 1):

You are just looking for the `MAX(JobCardNo)` for each `custnm`:

```
select MAX(JobCardNo) as JobCardNo, custnm 
FROM JobCardDetails 
GROUP BY custnm
ORDER BY JobCardNo DESC
```

Comment: Interesting approach.